# Why do we ignore the Flux - Luminosity relation when deriving the Eddington Luminosity?

Tags: stellar-physics, luminosity

I was just doing the derivation for the Eddington Luminosity by considering the momentum equation,

$$ -\frac{Gm}{4\pi r^4} = \frac{dP}{dm} $$

and the radiative transport pressure

$$ \frac{dT}{dr} = - \frac{3 \kappa \rho }{4ac T^3} \frac{F}{4 \pi r^2} $$

paired with the radiation pressure

$$ P_{rad} = \frac{1}{3} a T^4 $$

Taking the ratio of the hydrostatic pressure and the radiation pressure we get

$$ dP_{rad}/dP \leq 1 $$

Which gives

$$ F = \frac{4\pi c Gm}{\kappa} $$

**We then immediately jump to the Eddington luminosity**

$$ L_{Edd} = \frac{4\pi c Gm}{\kappa} $$

**without taking into consideration that**

$$ F = \frac{L}{4 \pi r^2} $$

**Why? We have carried the constants through all this way so why do just now only consider the proportionality of F with L and not the complete relationship?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is at least one mistake in what you've written above. The radiative diffusion equation is
$$ \frac{d(aT^4)}{dr} = -\frac{3 \kappa \rho}{c} F_{rad}$$
$$\frac{dT}{dr} = -\frac{3 \kappa \rho}{4acT^3} F_{rad}$$
(I think you have mixed up $F$ and $L$ in your second equation, and the answer may be as simple as that).

Radiation pressure is
$$P_{rad} = \frac{a}{3}T^4 $$

Hydrostatic equilibrium (assuming only radiation pressure)
$$ \frac{dP_{rad}}{dr} = - \rho g$$
$$ \frac{4aT^{3}}{3}\frac{dT}{dr} = -\rho g$$
$$ \frac{4a T^3}{3} \frac{3\kappa \rho}{4acT^3} F_{rad} = \rho g = \rho G \frac{M}{r^2}$$
Therefore, assuming that all of the luminosity is due to radiation
$$ 4\pi r^2 F_{rad} = L_{rad} = \frac{4\pi GM c}{\kappa}$$

EDIT: After the exchange about the Prialnik book you used, it seems there is confusion over the definition of $F$. I have used $F_{rad}$ to be a *flux*, that is power per unit area. Prialnik's definition of $F$ is a power. Thus using Prialnik's definition then indeed $F= L_{edd}$ at the surface and the final equation in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point but I took that equation from Prialnik's book "Theory of Stellar Structure and Evolution" - Chapter 3, page 50.

My lecturer does the proof in the manner I have done above.

Comment: @PPG Your Eq 2 is only dimensionally correct if $F$ has units of power. I have Prialnik's "Introduction to stellar structure and evolution" (2000) and I see the problem. On p.52 of that book, Prialnik defines $F$ as the "total flux crossing a spherical surface" - i.e. it's a luminosity! In ch.2 Prialnik says that $F$ is defined as having the dimensions of power. So in her version, yes $F = L_{edd}$ at the surface and it is the final equation of your OP that is mistaken.